# TypeScript closure scope error: The name does not exist in the current scope

Tags: javascript, typescript

does anyone know why **test1** fails to compile?

```
class Y { public myMethod: any; };
class QQ { public test(name, fun: () => any) { } }

var qq = new QQ();
qq.test("Run test1", () => {

        var outer = 10;

        Y.prototype.myMethod = () => {

          // Error: The name 'outer' does not exist in the current scope
            outer = 11;
        }
});
```

But the following works:

```
   qq.test("Run test2", () => {

            var outer = 10;
            var fun = ()=> { outer = 11; };

            Y.prototype.myMethod = fun;
    });
```

The **JavaScript** version of the required code would look look like this:

```
qq.test("Run test1", function () {
    var outer = 10;

    Y.prototype.myMethod = function () {
        outer = 11;
    };
});
```

The outer function declares a variable "outer" within its closure, which should naturally be visible to the inner function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in TypeScript until verion 0.8.2 that has [been fixed since then](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/341).

Answer (score 1):

Shortened to just the salient points:

This is the JavaScript I think you are expecting.

```
var Y = (function () {
    function Y() { }
    Y.prototype.myMethod = function () {
    };
    return Y;
})();
var QQ = (function () {
    function QQ() { }
    QQ.prototype.test = function (name, fun) {
        fun();
    };
    return QQ;
})();
var qq = new QQ();
qq.test("Run test1", function () {
    var _this = this;
    _this.outer = 10;
    Y.prototype.myMethod = function () {
        alert(_this.outer);
    };
});
var y = new Y();
y.myMethod();
```

You need to change your TypeScript to get this output:

```
class Y { 
    public myMethod() {

    }
}

class QQ {
    public test(name, fun: () => any) { // updated signature
        fun(); // call the function
    }
}

var qq = new QQ();

qq.test("Run test1", () => {
        this.outer = 10; // use this.
        Y.prototype.myMethod = () => {
            alert(this.outer);
        }
});

var y = new Y();
y.myMethod();
```

And yes, TypeScript believes `this.outer` to be a problem in the alert statement, but compiles the correct JavaScript anyway. You can raise that as a bug at http://typescript.codeplex.com.

Comment: Sohnee, I don't quite follow. There are two lambda expressions here. The outer lambda defines a variable "outer" and then assigns the inner lambda to some object's prototype. The outer lambda defines a closure, which means that all objects within the outer closure should be visible within the inner closure. This is very standard JavaScript - nothing at all funky about it. I believe this is a bug in the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: @NoelAbrahams clarification needed - I have posted a JavaScript example and questioned what difference you expect.

Comment: '@Sohnee, I've edited the question to show the expected result. The solution you have proposed does not seem natural to me, a "this" in a lambda seems strange. I'll raise this as a bug, if there is nothing more. Thanks.